# Using array with prepaired statment php, mysql, skip over empty strings

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Having some issues learning prepaired statments for mysql.

I hade everything working then i got a new problem, The initial problem was i wanted to skip over empty strings in a mysql update form (ie: user profile).

I tried to programaticly do it in php, but i dont understand prepaired statments enough to do this, i keep reading but i am having no success can you help me in making this work as intended? Essentialy im trying to use a array in a prepaired statment.

```
if (empty($email) && empty($fullname)  && empty($address) && empty($country) && empty($state) && empty($city) && empty($postcode) && empty($phone) && empty($password) && empty($random_salt)) {
  echo "Nothing to do....";
  return;
}
else { 
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $country = $_POST['country'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $merchantID = $_POST['merchantId'];

        // The hashed password from the form
    $password = $_POST['p']; 
    $pass2 = $password;
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    $random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax()), true));

    $password = hash('sha512', $password.$random_salt);

    $updates = array();
    if (!empty($email))
      $updates[] = 'email="'.$email.'"';
    if (!empty($address))
      $updates[] = 'address="'.$address.'"';
    if (!empty($country))
      $updates[] = 'country="'.$country.'"';
    if (!empty($state))
      $updates[] = 'state="'.$state.'"';
    if (!empty($city))
      $updates[] = 'city="'.$city.'"';
    if (!empty($postcode))
      $updates[] = 'postcode="'.$postcode.'"';
    if (!empty($phone))
      $updates[] = 'phone="'.$phone.'"';
    if (!empty($password))
      $updates[] = 'password="'.$password.'"';
    if (!empty($random_salt))
      $updates[] = 'salt="'.$random_salt.'"';

    $updates = implode(', ', $updates);

  if ($update_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE table SET ? WHERE id = ".$merchantID)) {
    $update_stmt->execute($updates);
    $update_stmt->close();
    //    
    echo '<br><p>';
    echo '<a href="homepage.com"> Account infomation update was a success...</a>';
  }
  else {
    echo "oppps, update didnt work, please report this to admin";
  }

}
```

Now i think i have strayed, no matter why i try i cant seem to work out how to do this, granted i dont fully understand prepaired statments im trying.

Comment: A prepared statement means your `SET` looks like `SET phone = ?, salt = ?, etc`.  Your statement doesn't look anything like that.  http://mattbango.com/notebook/code/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/

Comment: thanks cale, so really the only way to do it would be to make a 10 or so different blind_params to match the different prepair statments? see what im trying to acomplish above? surly there is a easyier way?
now my set looks like SET phone = $phone, salt = $salt, etc..

Comment: Sure.  PDO makes it easier, if you're willing to use that.  Otherwise, this write-up covers what you are after: http://www.pontikis.net/blog/dynamically-bind_param-array-mysqli

Comment: ok i think PDO is the way ill go, ill have to read more, seems alot simpler...

Comment: unfortuantly it dosnt a answer would be appreciated